# SAP B1: How to check if new data was inserted in OIVL table

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

In SAP B1, I wanted to count data that is created 3 hours prior to current time.

I already have this logic

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM OIVL T0
WHERE T0.CreateDate >= DATEADD(hour, -12, GETDATE())
```

But the problem is the `CreateDate` column only contains Date, without time.

*It has time but in smallint*

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Comment: What does _"It has time but in smallint"_ mean? There are 86,400 seconds in a day but `smallint` only has a range of +/-32k, so does this field only hold the hours and minutes portion of the time? As 0-1,439 minutes, or some other encoding such as hours*100 + minutes?

Comment: A lot of time fields in B1 are stored as hours*100 + mins

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the CreateTime dataType is smallint, but it stores only hour and minute in HHMM format. meaning 4 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the discussion in comments about how CreateTime is encoded by SAP B1, you're going to need to compute each row's datetime value to compare it with the current time, e.g.:

```sql
create table #Example (
  CreateDate date,
  CreateTime smallint
);
insert #Example (CreateDate, CreateTime) values ('2020-08-30', 2324);

select
  CreateDate,
  CreateTime,
  CreateDateTime --2020-08-30 23:24:00.000
from #Example
outer apply (
  select dateadd(mi, (CreateTime/100)*60+CreateTime%100, cast(CreateDate as datetime)) as CreateDateTime
) Calc
where CreateDateTime >= dateadd(hour, -12, getdate());
```

Comment: Here's what I did basing on your logic:

`SELECT 
*
FROM OIVL T0
OUTER APPLY (
 SELECT DATEADD(MI, (CreateTime/100)*60+CreateTime%100, cast(CreateDate as datetime)) as CreateDateTime
) Calc
where CreateDateTime >= dateadd(hour, -3, GETDATE())`

This solved my question. Wow. Thanks

Comment: I never though of using Outer Apply.